# Inertia Responses

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm using Inertia with Vue3. I did not understand clearly the responses. If someone make this example clear for me, I believe I'll understand the logic. Sorry if it's a silly question.

I have a simple post form:
title
description

and also a "tags" section; which user can use the existed tags, or they can create a new tag and here it is the problem.

When I submit a new tag, I want to retrieve the data and push it into the tags props on the onSuccess state and keep the title and description sections. But I do not know how to deal with it, I can not return any json data on my server side, even if I can, I do not want to send a json data manually, if I have to use ajax or xhr request manually what is the point of using Inertia.Thanks.

I want to retrieve the inserted data on the onSucess state. I checked it out the inertia docs but did not get it.

Passing the data from the controller:

```
defineProps({
    tags: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    styles: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
})

const tags = ref(page.props.tags);
const styles = ref(page.props.styles);

let addTag = () => {
    tagForm.post('/tags', {
        preserveScroll: true,
        resetOnSuccess: false,
        onSuccess: () => do_the_job_here, //push the inserted tag into the tags
    })
};
```

Server Side:

```
$data = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
]);

$tag = Tag::create($data);
//pass the $tag here
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no direct way. It can be done in this hacky way, though.

Change your `App\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests` middleware to have a data key in Shared data

```
public function share(Request $request): array
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'auth.user' => \Auth::user(),
        'flash' => [
            'error' => fn () => $request->session()->get('error'),
            'success' => fn () => $request->session()->get('success'),
            'data' => fn () => $request->session()->get('data') // add this line
        ],
    ]);
}
```

While processing your request on the server side, you can do something like this:

```
public function submitTagForm()
{
    // process form data

    return redirect()->back()
        ->with('success', 'Settings saved successfully')
        ->with('data', ["one"=> "one", "two"=> "two"]); // add this extra line to pass desired data
}
```

Finally, in your Inertia.Js code, you can simply access any data passed:

```
addTag.post('tags', {
    preserveScroll: true,
    resetOnSuccess: false,
    onSuccess: (response) => {
        console.log(response.props.flash.data);
    }
})
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But I believe it is not a valid solution. For example; when you use Laravel's "redirect" method, in the response.props you can see you are reloading all the page. It means you are making requests to your dB for the tags and styles or whatever you pass from the controller. It brings us to the solution and problem itself of course, I can see the new tags structure in the response.props.tags section so I can grab the updated tags array over here but reloading all the page only for this process does not make sense, so it is unnecessary to use shared data in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use tagForm, You can handle it on front side.

```
> let addTag = () => {
>     tagForm.post('/tags', {
>         preserveScroll: true,
>         resetOnSuccess: false,
>         onSuccess: () => this.tagForm   // you can access form here as well user input >Tag .
>     }) };
```